# Integral f(x+1) from (0 to n-1) equal Integral f(x) from (1 to n)?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How is this? I am sure I am missing something very obvious.

$$\int_0^{n-1} f(x+1)dx = \int_1^n f(x)dx$$

Comment: Who is this $f$?

Comment: Any function from R+ to R+.

Comment: Then take $f(x) = x$, and $n = 2$: the first integral is $1/2$ and the second is $3/2$.

Comment: $x-1$, not $x+1$. This is an elementary change of variable.

Comment: Graphically, this can be interpreted as follows: the signed area under a curve is translation invariant.

Comment: Why did you do the last change?

Comment: I did not read the question correctly. It really was trivial, I did not read it right.

Comment: Use u-substitution $u=x+1$, $du=dx$ in order to solve this. I think question is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to the original question

Suppose $n>1$:
$$
\int_0^{n-1}f(x)\,dx=\int_1^{n}f(x)\,dx
$$
This implies
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_{n-1}^nf(x)\,dx
$$
and it is easy to find an example of a function that hasn't this property.

### Answer to the edited question (first edit)

It is trivial: just do a change of variables:
$$
\int_0^{n-1}f(x)\,dx=\dots[x=t+1]\dots=
\int_1^{n}f(t+1)\,dt=
\int_1^{n}f(x+1)\,dx
$$
How you call the variable in the last integral is immaterial.

### Answer to the further edit

The claim is false.

Comment: ` f(x) = e^x ` ?

Comment: @K0d3R Use dollar signs not ' for math mode

Comment: @K0d3R Yes, that's an easy instance. Or think to a function that's zero on $[1,\infty)$ and has $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx>0$.

Comment: How is the current claim false?

Comment: Thanks for pointing my stupidity ! Cheers :-(

Comment: ^ What you mean? :O